# Unique values not working in R shiny selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, unique

I want a multiple selection of columns from a data set, and then have another multiple selection of UNIQUE values in the selected columns.  Right now the unique feature does not seem to be working.  It duplicates the values of which over column selection has the most unique values.

```
    ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(fluidRow(column(width = 4, 

    uiOutput("variants"),
    uiOutput("variants2")
    )
)))

server <-shinyServer( function(input, output, session) { 

  df<-somedata


  output$variants <- renderUI({
      selectInput ("choose_columns", 
                        "Choose Attribute", 
                        sort(unique(names(df)), decreasing = FALSE),
                        selected="",
                        multiple =TRUE)

  })


  dat<-reactive({
     unique(df[,input$choose_columns])
    })



  output$variants2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput ('further', 
                  'Choose Attribute(s) Value(s)', 
                  dat(), 
                  selected="", 
                  multiple = TRUE)
    })  



})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work for me. I used the `mtcars` dataset as an example. My only suggestion is to have `df<-somedata` outside (before) your `server` code. This way the data will not be reloaded every time the user modifies inputs. Below is my code with `mtcars`:

```
ui<-shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 4, 
        uiOutput("variants"),
        uiOutput("variants2")
      )
    )
  )
)

library(datasets)
data("mtcars")

server <- shinyServer( function(input, output, session) { 

  output$variants <- renderUI({
    selectInput ("choose_columns", 
      "Choose Attribute", 
      sort(unique(names(mtcars)), decreasing = FALSE),
      selected="",
      multiple =TRUE)
    })

  dat<-reactive({
    unique(mtcars[,input$choose_columns])
  })

  output$variants2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput('further', 
      'Choose Attribute(s) Value(s)', 
      dat(), 
      selected="", 
      multiple = TRUE)
    })  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Even having the dataset outside the serve the unique feature is not working like I want it to.  Choose 'cyl' and 'hp in mtcars.  I want the 'Choose Attribute(s) Value(s) drop down to only have ONE '6', '4', and '8' under 'cyl'.  Right now it has multiple.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying. It seems that if shiny defaults to the lowest common multiple of the unique values of the two selected variables. Not sure why this is or how to get rid of it. Perhaps one way would be to create separate `further` `selectInput`s for each `choose_columns` `selectInput` selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing dat(), you'll see that values may repeat inside each column but never will an entire row be equal to another. The `selectInput`is only breaking dat() by columns. One way to get unique values by column at the `selectInput` is using:

```
dat<-reactive({
  lapply(mtcars[,input$choose_columns], unique)
})
```